# Serving Django and Vue with Nginx

Tags: django, vue.js, nginx

I have a website which uses Django for the API and Vue for the frontend. Currently when I deploy the site I do the following:

- Create a production build of the Vue app (`npm run build`)
- Copy the Vue `dist` folder into a specific folder within the Django app
- One of the Django urls is setup as a `TemplateView` which serves up the Vue `index.html`

By doing the above, `Nginx` in production simply serves up the Django app using `gunicorn` and everything works.

However I would prefer to have Nginx serve up the Vue `index.html` and static files. For example `/` will serve the Django app and `/spa` will serve the Vue app which will itself call the api.

Here is my current `Nginx` config:

```
upstream appserver_wsgi_app {
  server localhost:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/user/static_django_files/;
    }

    location /media {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/user/media_django_files/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            if (!-f $request-filename) {
                proxy_pass http://appserver_wsgi_app;
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

What needs to be changed in `Nginx` so that it will serve the `Vue index.html` and `static files` as well as the `Django` app? Also, does anything need to change on the Vue side since im currently just calling the api as follows:

```
axios.post("/api/dosomething/", data)
```

**EDIT**

I have added the following to my nginx config and uploaded the Vue dist folder:

```
    location /spa {
        autoindex on;
        alias /path/to/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

I have also added the following to `vue.config.js`:

```
baseUrl: '/spa'
```

And to my `Vue Router`: `mode: history`

When restarting nginx, the `index.html` page for the vue app attempts to load in the browser but it cannot find the `css` and `js` files which it tries to find at:

```
www.example.com/spa/js/...
www.example.com/spa/css/...
```

Comment: The Vue files are just static files. You can do exactly the same thing as you have already done for /static and /media.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've made a little progress, it seems to almost be working. Please could you look at the EDIT in my post with the current issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar setup where I run the Django REST backend with uwsgi on port 8090 and serve the production build of angular 4 frontend via nginx. Here is my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name **url**;
    rewrite     ^   https:// **url** $request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  **url**;
    ssl_certificate **.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key **.key;

    root *path to your vue production build folder where index.html resides*;
    index index.html;

    error_page 502 /gateway.html;

    location /assests {
        autoindex on;
        alias *path to you Django assets *;
    }
    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias *path to you static files both django static files and vue related static files*;
    }

    // this to server the django admin
    location /manage/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090/manage/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    // this is for the REST backend
    location /api/{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

I think similar setup should work for Django + Vue.js project. Let me know if it works.

** EDIT
for your second issue create another location with '/spa/static' in nginx.conf similar to the '/static'.

Comment: What should be given in `config.js` ?