# Deploying Vue-Django-graphene on NGINX

Tags: django, vue.js, nginx, graphql

I apologise if this question is considered answered, however it seems that in my specific circumstances other solutions haven't managed to solve my issue so far. I have a django-vue project which uses GraphQL to communicate between vue and django.

I am trying to serve my web app with uwsgi and NGINX, and the Django portion works fine, however there seems to be some issues when looking for the Vue /dist/ static files e.g. get http://ip.ip.ip.ip:8000/js/app.js ERR_ABORTED 404, same goes for CSS for the app and chunk-vendors.

This is unfortunately my first deployment so my understanding is fairly shaky, however it seems pretty clear that NGINX doesn't understand the path to the dist folder correctly, but the variations I've tried so far haven't managed to get it to work.

mysite_nginx.conf:

```
# hubdev_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///srv/hub/hub.sock;
#   server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

# configuration for the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen 8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name ip.ip.ip.ip;
    charset utf-8

    root    /srv/hub/frontend/dist/;
    index   index.html;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size    75M;    # 'Adjust to taste'

    # Django media
    # none yet

    # Django static - I've tried both of these
    location /static {
    alias /srv/hub/staticfiles;
#   alias /srv/hub/frontend/dist;
    }

    # send all non-media requests to the Django server
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /srv/hub/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I've looked at this question which seems to be similar: [Serving Django and Vue with Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220698/serving-django-and-vue-with-nginx)

but this section of one of the answers doesn't make much sense in terms of how you combine both the paths in one...

```
location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias *path to you static files both django static files and vue related static files*;
    }
```

urlpatterns in urls.py:

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    url(r'^dmedia/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        {'document_root': os.path.join(settings.VUE_ROOT, 'media')}),
    url(r'^img/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        {'document_root': os.path.join(settings.VUE_ROOT, 'img')}),
    url(r'^js/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        {'document_root': os.path.join(settings.VUE_ROOT, 'js')}),
    url(r'^css/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        {'document_root': os.path.join(settings.VUE_ROOT, 'css')}),
    url(r'^fonts/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        {'document_root': os.path.join(settings.VUE_ROOT, 'fonts')}),
    url(r'^graphql', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True))),
```

Where VUE_ROOT is defined in the prod settings to be "\frontend\dist" - this works fine on my windows dev environment.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be to create separate locations for each resource which NGINX fails to load. In my case it was adding:

```
location /dist {
    alias /srv/hub/frontend/dist;
    autoindex    on;
    }
```

which then presented errors in sourcing the img files used in the Vue application.

thus:

```
location /img {
    alias    /srv/hub/frontend/dist/img;
}
```

I highly doubt that's optimum best practise but it works now and I'm glad I can move on...